# Kill parent and child thread by reading status of a variable from Child thread in python

Tags: python-3.x, multithreading, python-2.7, python-multithreading

My program takes input as a json file and runs various functions on the parameters by creating threads for each argument passed.Now i want to create sub-threads from these multiple parent threads which would monitor an alarm, if the alarm goes off the sub-thread and its corresponding parent thread should stop.

So the Child thread is an alarm monitoring thread if it sees the alarm is True it should kill the corresponding parent thread without affecting any other threads.

The flow is [Flow of THREADS](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2tmfI.jpg)

Comment: Welcome to SO Manish Jain! This question is far too broad for SO so I'm flagging to close. SO is designed for getting help with specific programming problems. Your question reads more like the scope for a job so isn't really suitable.

Comment: Is this not a specific programming problem??